# How to NgFor using in ng2 smart table?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services, ng2-smart-table

Above I have mentioned my Component.ts column names in that pname(product_name)

it was an dropdown so i need Ngfor to list out by product names  I don't how to

add Ngfor condition in ng2 smart table.

**component.ts**

```
this.service.get_type().subscribe(pro => {
       console.log(this.data=pro)
       console.log(this.val)
       this.settings = {
        mode: 'inline',
        hideSubHeader: false,

        add: {
          addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
          createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
          cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
          confirmCreate :true,
        },
        edit: {
          editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
          saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
          cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
          confirmSave:true,
        },
        delete: {
          deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
          confirmDelete: true,
        },
        columns: {         
          slno: {
            title: 'S.No.',
            type: 'string',
            width:'1%',
          },
          ptype: {
            title: 'Product Type',
            type:'string',
            width:'50%',
            editor: {
              type:'list',
              config:{
                list:this.data
              }
            }

          },

          pname: {
            title: 'Product Name',
            type:'string',
            width:'35%',
            valuePrepareFunction: (data) => { return this.data[0]['type'] },

          },
          pdiscription: {
            title: 'Product Description ',
            type:'string',
            width:'50%',
          },
          qty: {
            title: 'QTY',
            type: 'string',
            width:'5%',
          },
          rate: {
            title: 'Rate',
            type: 'string',
            width:'5%',
          },
      amount: {
        title: 'Amount',
        type: 'string',
        width:'10%',
        valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => {
          console.log(row);
          console.log(row.id);
          return row.qty * row.rate
        },
      },

      tax: {
        title: 'Tax',
        selectMode: 'multi',
        filter: {
          type: 'checkbox',
          config: {
            true: 'Yes',
            false: 'No',
            resetText: 'clear',
          },
        },
        editor:{
          type: 'checkbox',
          config: {
            true: 'Yes',
            false: 'No',
            resetText: 'clear',
          }
        }
      }


},

   }
 },
    error => console.log(error));
```

Above I have mentioned my Component.ts column names in that pname(product_name)

it was an dropdown so i need Ngfor to list out by product names  I don't how to

add Ngfor condition in ng2 smart table.